# Why does accessing the localStorage object in Internet Explorer throw an error?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, local-storage, modernizr

I'm working on a client issue where Modernizr unexpectedly does not detect the support for the `localStorage` object in Internet Explorer 9. My page correctly uses the HTML 5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) and the developer tools report the page has a Browser Mode of IE9 and a Document Mode of IE9 standards so I would expect this to work.

I've debugged into the following `try`/`catch` block in Modernizr and discovered a JavaScript error is thrown as soon as the `localStorage` object is accessed.

```
tests['localstorage'] = function() {
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(mod, mod);
        localStorage.removeItem(mod);
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

On some machines the message of the JavaScript error is `The system cannot find the file specified.`. On others it is just `Invalid argument.` and Internet Explorer blocks for exactly 5 minutes before it throws the error.

**What is causing accessing the `localStorage` object to throw an error here on Internet Explorer?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've discovered if the lowest level subdomain matches one of the reserved device names as documented at [Restrictions on the File Mask and File Name Properties](https://web.archive.org/web/20141231102443/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578688.aspx) on Internet Explorer then accessing the `localStorage` object will throw an error.

This problem is likely happening because internally Internet Explorer is attempting to access the file system using a reserved device name when accessing the `localStorage` object in order to satisfy the [`Storage` object initialization steps](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute).

It's certainly very much an edge case but if your page is comes from a server whose lowest level subdomain is exactly any of `con`, `prn`, `aux`, `clock$`, `nul`, `com1`, `com2`, `com3`, `com4`, `com5`, `com6`, `com7`, `com8`, `com9`, `lpt1`, `lpt2`, `lpt3`, `lpt4`, `lpt5`, `lpt6`, `lpt7`, `lpt8`, or `lpt9` (e.g. `http://prn.example.com`) then this could well the reason why you are seeing this problem.

Choosing a lower level subdomain that wasn't a reserved device name in this situation solved the problem.

Comment: That was a wordy, involved answer to your own question that was asked only 1 minute prior...

Comment: @kinakuta do you imply the answer was already written when the question is posted? Still doesn't imply malice, just the want to share.

Comment: @JanDvorak didn't say anything about it being malicious. I don't mind if people want to share, but it just seems curious if it's not presented that way.

Comment: Yep, I did indeed have my answer good to go when I posted the question. Sure, it's very much an edge case but hopefully this will save someone else with exactly this problem some time one day! :)

Comment: Has anybody reported this issue to Microsoft? This sounds like a high severity bug to me.

Answer (score 4):

We hit a similar issue because we ran CCleaner on the machine.

To solve:

Internet Options -> Browsing History -> Delete:

Make sure to check all options except the very first one (Preserve Favorite website data).

We were able to fix, then reproduce this issue by using CCleaner again, then fix again.

Go to this site for more information: http://grekai.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/localstorage-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/