# LocalStorage not working on IE 11 Win 8.1

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, local-storage

Basically i'm trying to remove few localstorage keys from my page.
The script I'm using is:

```
    box.emptyStorageFilter = (function() {
        $('header nav li a').off().on('click', function(e) {
            localStorage.removeItem('list_customers');
            localStorage.removeItem('list_orders');
            localStorage.removeItem('list_products');
            localStorage.removeItem('filter_category');
        });
    }());
```

I have no idea what's wrong, since it's working on EVERY browser (including IE 8,9,10) but IE 11!

At the console I get this Error:

> SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102116/access-denied-for-localstorage-in-ie10). It can even be your anti-virus software.

Comment: Cant. I havent anti-virus.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392872/why-does-accessing-the-localstorage-object-in-internet-explorer-throw-an-error

Comment: I think this will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20848924/7035175

Answer (score 1):

local storage does not work in local mode it's a security thing (but it can be made 2) http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/61177c2b-6a38-4207-9cbe-ccd6c86b1d42/html5-local-storage-broken-in-ie11-win-81-x64-error-function-expected#f345c94d-f404-4b4b-b808-d8849646be27 please post an update if you find anything...

Comment: Didnt find anything :/